# Showing non-western language from right to left in libgdx (Android)

Tags: android, fonts, libgdx, bitmap-fonts

This is my problem:

I'm using Hiero to generate a font for my libgdx game (files .fnt and .png).I success to generate a custom font, but for laguage like arabic (writing text from right to left). i show the result starting from left to right but me i want to show it from right to left.
example:
For the world
 "النتيجة"
I show in the game :"ةج ي ت ن لا"

I if any one have a procedure/ or experience whith a non-western language how to showing the text from right to left?.
thanks.